# Looping through item with classname and hide them

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

So I pretty sure my loop is correct, however it seems to only hide the first element and leave the rest behind (it still outputs the results fine...)

```
var Sender = document.getElementsByClassName("portlet-section-body caf-primary-row")
var Senders = Sender.length;


//console.log(Sender[0].cells[3].innerHTML)

var excludedSenders = ["REKONDIS SE (Rekondis Sweden)", "SE_201024_LRF_Media (LRF Media)", "SE_201461_Dustin (Dustin)"]
console.log("Senders " + Sender.length);
console.log("excludedSenders " + excludedSenders.length);


for (var i = 0; i < Senders; i++){
console.log(Sender[i]);
    for (var j = 0; j < excludedSenders.length; j++){
        if (Sender[i].cells[3].innerHTML.indexOf(excludedSenders[j]) != -1){
            Sender[i].hide()
        }
    }
}
```

The items 
[image]

The items after running javascript 
[image]

How comes it does find all the items, but only hides 1?

Comment: Just a thought: try changing 'var' in your for-loops to 'let'.

Comment: Hi sorry sender is ```var Sender = document.getElementsByClassName("portlet-section-body caf-primary-row")```

Comment: Try to replace innerHTML to innerText.

Comment: @MichaelBeeson I just tried that, same result.

Comment: @Pinetree just tried, same result. Even combined with "let" instead of "var" in the for-loop.

Comment: can you post also the html part

Answer (score 0):

okay the problem is because you are hiding the element and then trying to access the other cells

```
var Sender = document.getElementsByClassName("portlet-section-body caf-primary-row")
var Senders = Sender.length;

var excludedSenders = ["REKONDIS SE (Rekondis Sweden)", "SE_201024_LRF_Media (LRF Media)", "SE_201461_Dustin (Dustin)"]
var excludedSendersLength = excludedSenders.length;

for (let i = 0; i < Senders; i++){
    for (let j = 0; j < excludedSenders; j++){
        if (Sender[i].cells[3].innerHTML.indexOf(excludedSenders[j]) != -1) {
            Sender[i].hide()
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that, no success.

Comment: I've tested it, it was working on my side even though had to recreate a case for the html

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
const Sender          = document.getElementsByClassName("portlet-section-body caf-primary-row")
,     excludedSenders = [ "REKONDIS SE (Rekondis Sweden)"
                        , "SE_201024_LRF_Media (LRF Media)"
                        , "SE_201461_Dustin (Dustin)"
                        ]
;

for (let e_Sender of Sender)
{
  console.log(e_Sender.cells[3].textContent);

  for (let ex_Sender of excludedSenders)
  {
    if (e_Sender.cells[3].textContent.indexOf(ex_Sender) > -1)
    {
      e_Sender.hide()
      break
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Also removes just 1.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/C44a5lS.png
https://i.imgur.com/ZVn2oQE.png - result

Comment: I have changed the `console.log` to better see what happens

Comment: @xNoncombat  I have changed the console.log to better see what happens, could do show again capture image result, ??

Comment: It seems to skip items...

https://i.imgur.com/ZHT0PeZ.png

I also tried to change background color, I could clearly see it skips for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue!

There are 2 classes.

```
portlet-section-body caf-primary-row
portlet-section-alternate caf-primary-row
```

Which explains why it wouldn't work, really weird it uses 2 different classes.
I wanna thank you all for helping and your time.

Comment: better to use `document.querySelectorAll('#tableID tbody tr')` instead of  `getElementsByClassName`